# Asignar un valor a una variable Output en SQL Server y recuperar valor C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, server

Buen día, tengo un procedimiento almacenado que lo que hace es comparar si una variable de salida que se le es mandada ya esta como registro en la BD, si es así simplemente actualiza los datos, pero si no está agrega el nuevo registro.

```
create proc sp_act_agg
@articuloID int output, @nombre varchar(50), @descripcion varchar(500), @precio numeric(12,2), @fam int as
begin
    if exists(select * from ARTICULOS where ArtID = @articuloID)
    begin
        
        update ARTICULOS set ArtNombre = @nombre, ArtDescripcion = @descripcion, ArtPrecio = @precio where ArtID = @articuloID

        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            raiserror('ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR EL ARTÍCULO', 16, 1)
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        
        insert ARTICULOS(ArtNombre, ArtDescripcion, ArtPrecio, FamID) values(@nombre, @descripcion, @precio, @fam)
        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            raiserror('ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR LA TABLA ARTÍCULOS', 16, 1)
        end
        set @articuloID = @@IDENTITY

    end
end
go
```

en C# tengo el siguiente método para ejecutar dicho procedimiento:

```
public int AgregarActualizaArticulos(int clave, string nombre, string descripcion, double precio, int familia)
{
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();

    comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
    comando.CommandText = "sp_act_agg";
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", descripcion);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", precio);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam", familia);

    SqlParameter cl = new SqlParameter("@articuloID", SqlDbType.Int);
    cl.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cl.Value = clave;
    comando.Parameters.Add(cl);

    int filas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(filas > 0)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(comando.Parameters["@articuloID"].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Mi duda surge al momento de querer mandar el valor que tengo en el parámetro clave, no sé si esa sea la forma correcta (que lo dudo ya que no me da el resultado esperado) ya que aunque ingrese una clave que ya esté en la BD siempre se crea otro nuevo registro en vez de actualizar el que estoy especificando.

Les agradecería si pudieran aclarar mi duda, gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, el detalle era que

```
cl.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

la tenía especificada como una variable de salida, cuando debería de ser InputOutput.